# Google Sheets: Get First Value in Column

Tags: google-sheets-formula

I need to find the **first** value in a column range.  I've previously had help to find the **last** value in a column range,  such as:

```
=INDEX(E4:E188, MATCH(999^99, (E4:E188)))
```

However I haven't figured out how to convert the above formula to return the first value instead.  Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand your expected result, how about the following sample formula?

#### Sample formula:

```
=INDEX(FILTER(E4:E188,E4:E188),1)
```

#### Testing:

[image]

#### Reference

- [FILTER](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093197)